# $\epsilon$-greedy policy in environments where actions are performed in a long term. Does it has influence?

Tags: deep-rl, dqn, epsilon-greedy-policy

I'm working in an environment where once an action $a \in A$ is performed, it must hold this action selection for a while. To clarify this, assumes a horizon length $h$ and the set of actions: $\{a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}\} \in A$. Assumes now that the length $h$ to converge for an optimal solution must be split by 3 where each action is applied distinctly because if one of these actions is selected twice during an episode, the reward penalizes it severely in such way that there's no possible policy that can get a better return than selects each action just once. Thus, the length of each of "sub-horizon" $h_{i}$ is $h_{i} > 0$ and $h_{i} < h - 2$.

Now seeing the DQN setting in the naive approach for exploration using $\epsilon$-greedy policy that selects at each time-step an action following:

```
n = random value between 0 and 1
if n < epsilon then:
   a = random action in A
else:
   a = maxQ(S, a)
```

For my particular problem (and probably many with similar settings), this way of selects an action seems oppositely and hard to converge for the optimal solution, shifting the distribution of samples for far from that. Does it make sense?

Actually, I believe that [sticky actions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.06009.pdf), could be way beneficial for many similar settings, beyond the scope of his original approach.